# websocket not responsing after some responses

Tags: python, api, networking, websocket, algorithmic-trading

The connection and handshake to the websocket successful.
After I receive some responses, the websocket stops responding and exits with code 1000 after a while.

The websocket

- is implemeted using python websoket library
- is of stock broker to get the latest traded price of stock
- allows unlimited request
- is running on system with avalbility of all required resources